# AngelScript, how to load a script file?

Tags: c++, load, execute

I know how I can bind C++ functions to AngelScript, but in my C++ code, how do I load an .as script file? How can I say in my C++ "Execute myscript.as now!" ?

In the AngelScript API I don't find any function like "LoadScript" or "ExecuteScript".
Or do I have to define a path somewhere from where AngelScript loads all scripts and I don't need to tell it the exact files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found it out (in a small side sentence in the docs):

AngelScript doesn't provide a build in file loading. That's why there is no API function. So the manual loading is indeed the only way.

Answer (score 1):

asIScriptModule::AddScriptSection will load a script string. asIScriptContext::Execute will execute a function from a script. [The documentation](http://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/sdk/docs/manual/index.html) was pretty clear about all of this; you might want to give it a look.